# If $A \in \mathcal{L}(H)$ and $\langle A(u),u \rangle \geq \langle u, u \rangle$, then $A$ is invertible.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, cauchy-sequences

**Exercise :**

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $A \in \mathcal{L}(H)$ such that :
>   $$\langle A(u),u \rangle \geq \langle u, u \rangle \; \forall u \in H$$
>   Show that $A$ is invertible.

**Attempt/Thoughts :**

The inequality given to hold can be transformed to 
$$\langle A(u),u \rangle \geq \|u\|^2$$
since $\|u\| = \sqrt{\langle u, u \rangle} $ by the definition of the inner product functional for Hilbert spaces.

Now, by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, one can yield :
$$|\langle Au, u\rangle| \leq \|Au\|\|u\|$$

Combining the two expressions now gives us :
$$\langle Au, u \rangle \geq \|u\|^2 \Rightarrow |\langle Au,u\rangle| \geq \|u\|^2  \Rightarrow \|Au\| \|u\| \geq \|u\|^2$$
$$\implies$$
$$\boxed{\|Au\| \geq \|u\|}$$
Now if I consider a sequence $\{u_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N} \subset H$ such that $Au_n \to u \in H$ then it would be :
$$\|A(u_n - u_m) \| \to 0 \implies \|u_n-u_m\| \to 0 \quad \text{for} \; n,m \to \infty$$
That means that $\{u_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is Cauchy and thus $A : H \to A(H)$ is injective $("1-1")$, thus invertible ?

**Is my approach correct ? Any tips, corrections and/or elaborations will be appreciated.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have shown that the image of $A$ is closed since if $A(u_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, so is $u_n$. Let $L$ be the adherence of $A(H)$, consider $u$ orthogonal to $L$, you have $0=\langle A(u),u\rangle\geq \langle u,u\rangle$, this implies that $u=0$, thus $L=X$. We deduce that $A$ is surjective, the open map theorem implies that $A$ is invertible.

Comment: Two questions : 1) Adherence is the same as closure $(\overline{A(H)})$ ? 2) As was pointed out in another answer, simply taking $Au = Av$ which shows that $u=v$ is sufficient to prove the invertibility or does my initial intuition (and thus your elaboration) provide a more rigorous result ?

Comment: adherence means closure, you to show surjectivity, injectivity is not enough.

Comment: Thank you. I almost foresaw that in order for an operator to be invertible, it should be both injective and surjective.

Answer (score 1):

If $Au = Av$ then $$\|u-v\| \le \|Au - Av\| = 0$$ so that $u=v$ too.